# White (blank, empty) space between values in an IF condition { }

Tags: razor, if-statement, whitespace, webmatrix

Simple question and probably simple answer, but I've tried a lot of things.

`How can I insert a white space between the 2 values ?`

I have tried quotation mark, double quotation mark, removing the ";", &nbsp, etc

```
@if(@providerData.CompanyName != null){

    @providerData.CompanyName;WHITESPACE;@providerData.CompanyType;
}
```

Comment: Nothing to do with your question, but it looks to me like the @ inside the parenthesis shouldn't be there:   @if( providerData.CompanyName ... )

Comment: Hello Knox. providerData is a variable (type "dynamic" holding result of a SQL dynamic query). The display / get the value in the HTML section/markup, we should us the "@" in razor syntax

Comment: We'll have to agree to disagree  :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may use `Html.Raw` method to put a white space there

```
@if(@providerData.CompanyName != null)
{
  @providerData.CompanyName@Html.Raw(" ")@providerData.CompanyType    
}
```

Alternatively you can use `@:` instead of `Html.Raw`

```
@if(@providerData.CompanyName != null)
{
  @providerData.CompanyName@: @providerData.CompanyType    
}
```

Comment: Any Ideas for the reason? What makes a `if` speacial?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old question now, but there's one more possible solution for the problem - use the `<text>` tag for this purpose. This tag itself won't be printed to your output but it will preserve the formatting you have inside of it.

```
@if(@providerData.CompanyName != null)
{
    <text>@providerData.CompanyName @providerData.CompanyType</text>
}
```

I think this way provides the cleanest syntax for what you want to achieve.